# Bootstrap v4 float-right doesn't work. [Replacement for pull-right]

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Basically, I have the latest version of bootstrap `Currently v4.0.0-beta.3` and I cannot get elements to align properly, with the official documentation. I searched online for solutions, but I found nothing. They all were about creating a new class with `right: 0;`, but that's not the point. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong, or is it just a bug?

I also found one post that sad that `flex` is the problem, but they didn't explain why or how can I fix it.

I even took their official example, from the documentation, it doesn't work.
Here's the example:

```
<div class="float-left">Float left on all viewport sizes</div><br>
<div class="float-right">Float right on all viewport sizes</div><br>
<div class="float-none">Don't float on all viewport sizes</div>
```

The result:

`Float left on all viewport sizesFloat right on all viewport sizesDon't float on 
 all viewport sizes`

I put them in a `div` with `row` class, nothing changed.

For those who don't know, Bootstrap removed `pull-right` class in the latest revision and replaced it with `float-right`.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you're seeing, and the exact code you're using?

Comment: Are any of the other Bootstrap 4.0b3 classes working? [It seems to work fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/q2ch06j7/)

Comment: This is actual code, just replaced the text inside and the output is copy-paste.

Comment: Yes, majority of them is working. Whole page is based on it at this moment.

Comment: If you want to push a div to the right inside a `row`, [use the `col` and `offset` classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns). `float-right` isn't meant to be used this way.

Comment: @OgnjenStefanovic By "the exact code you're using", I mean the entire (minimal) document, including `head` section and the place you link the Bootstrap libraries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In bootstrap, rows can only contain columns, so you must add at least one column inside the row

#### Fails

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="float-left">Float left on all viewport sizes</div><br>
  <div class="float-right">Float right on all viewport sizes</div><br>
  <div class="float-none">Don't float on all viewport sizes</div>
</div>
```

#### Works

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="float-left">Float left on all viewport sizes</div><br>
        <div class="float-right">Float right on all viewport sizes</div><br>
        <div class="float-none">Don't float on all viewport sizes</div>
    <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Bootstrap 5**

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<div class=vw-100> 
    <div class="row w-100">                   
        <div class="col">
            <h4 class="float-start" id="myid">my text</h4>
            <button type="button" class="float-end">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```